# How to populate all column names in PL/SQL developer?

Tags: plsql, keyboard-shortcuts, plsqldeveloper

In SQL developer if I type below statement and press `ctrl + space`, the list of all column names are displayed.

```
select * from mytable where
```

How to achieve the same in PL/SQL developer version 11.1?

Answer (score 2):

PL/sql developer has this feature... but:

1. the default key combination for invoking code-completion is F6, not CTRL+SPACE Why did they choose this key I have no idea. Luckily you can change all keyboard shortcuts in the program preferences
2. it can complete table names, but for fields it works only if you have already typed at least "mytable."  press  after the "." character and it will look up the fields of mytable.

"mytable" in point 2 can be also a table alias, if you have assigned an alias to the table you are querying:

```
  select t.<press F6 here> from mytable t
```

this code completion works also for stored procedure arguments, procedure names within packages, etc...

Comment: works only for table names. for columns I get ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE

Comment: " ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE" is most likely an issue with your oracle server (an internal error on the server side while executing the query plsql developer issues to get column names). Try to log onto another oracle server. I use it on a daily basis and I have more than 300 oracle servers to work on.

Comment: My db is fine, this is PL/SQL developer glitch

Comment: "ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE" happens surely because the server process dies, especially if it happens every time the client is trying to execute a given query that triggers an oracle bug. I have seen this happening many times and if you think oracle doesn't have bugs, well, you have been very lucky so far.  Anyway: which versions of 1) Oracle server, 2) Oracle Client installed on your machine 3) pl/sql developer are you using?